# wildfly NoSuchMethodError when running standalone.sh on Ubuntu

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to take a course on pluralsight that requires me to install wildfly. the course did not show how to install it and it was unclear to me so I watched [this video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjFRO1RQtQU). at [2:20](https://youtu.be/rjFRO1RQtQU?t=2m20s) in the video, the guy starts wildfly by running a script called standalone.sh. However, this script gives me a java exception:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/wildfly

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
    at org.jboss.modules.NamedClassLoader.<init>(NamedClassLoader.java:40)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.<init>(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:97)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.<init>(ModuleClassLoader.java:113)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.<init>(Module.java:246)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader$3.run(ModuleLoader.java:649)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader$3.run(ModuleLoader.java:644)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.defineModule(ModuleLoader.java:644)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:499)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:389)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:282)
    at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:87)
    at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:81)
    at __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory.changeDefaultFactory(__DocumentBuilderFactory.java:81)
    at __redirected.__JAXPRedirected.changeAll(__JAXPRedirected.java:53)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:393)
```

I have done some googling and I cannot find an answer online.

I am using openjdk 9 if that helps.

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Looks like wildfly does not use the Java Version you expected. The classloader wich is expected here is introduced in java9

Comment: Which Versions of Java are installed in your System?

Comment: @Jens as far as I can tell, I am using Java 9. (I have posted the output of "java -vesrion"). I realized that I had downloaded the Wildfly 11 Alpha and not wildfly 10 as the vidoes told me to. So I downloaded Wildfly 10 and now it works!

Comment: Try using Java 8. Java 9 is not yet final.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try install 'oficial' oracle jdk:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Finally, start the script with sudo

```
sudo ./standalone.sh
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The videos told me to download Wildfly 10 but I had instead downloaded Wildfly 11 Alpha. I still don't know why this error ocurrs but it works with Wildfly 10.